# Why is my webform returning a 404?

Tags: webforms

I have several webforms on the site, and all work as intended, except one, which throws a 404.  Everything seems to be as it should, so I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: hello JMichael, I suggest be be more specific with your question, for example, in what instance of your interaction with your webform is the 404? in  is Drupal 7 or 6?

Comment: Good point.  Hard to know what else to include, so I'll include what I can in an edit above.  Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: while doing the research to add the additional information, I discover the uid for the node was set to 0.  Updated that to 1 and the webform now appears.  Thanks for prompting!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. You should probably repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While doing the research to add the additional information, I discovered the uid for the node was set to 0. Updated that to 1 and the webform now appears.